# Crop Cover Photo like Google Plus using js & PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've seen few demos but not like Google+ In the Google+ if we upload Cover Photo then they made restrict minimum croppable area depend on uploaded image size and aspect ratio after that we can't make it smaller. Anyone have idea how to get Minimum width and height according to below points.

- First of get the aspect ratio of uploaded image by user.
- Then get Minimum width and height in pixel to allow croppable area after that area user will not able to make it small area for cropping cover photo which we want to restrict based on the image size & ratio.

For more information please have a look Google+ Cover Photo cropping style.

Below are few demos but what i'm looking for.

http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos/tutorial5.html

http://picturecut.tuyoshi.com.br/

Thanks in advance for your help!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long waiting i applied simply logic and it works for me as aspected.

```
var min_crop_width = (Original_Width / 100) * 83.5; // Minimum percentage
var min_crop_height = (min_crop_width / 5) * 1; // Your Standard Ratio...
min_crop_width = (min_crop_height * 5) / 1; // Your Standard Ratio...
```

Thanks!